How to model an "undefined" property in Cosmos Db from .net SDK
In Cosmos DB, it is possible to have the following, wherein the second phone number is "undefined"
Example 1
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"John",
   "phone":"12345"
}

Example 2
{
   "id": "2", 
   "name":"Scott"
}

This is easy to create and save from the data explorer.  However, in Code, I have a model which looks like this:
public class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone")]
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
}

Note that the phone is nullable.  So if left null, it ends up in the database as "phone" : null
However, what I would really like is for the entire field to be omitted, as in the example 2 above.  Is this possible?
The motivation is to save on space and RU's. For example, a class may have many nullable properties and it all adds up.
It seems to me that there could be an Attribute that could be put the phone property which means "if null, omit this property entirely"

Possible duplicates: Ignore null values when saving data in CosmosDb with Entity Framework, Removing properties with null values

Yes, is a duplicate, thanks for the link.
